# ERROR 1114 (HY000) at line 4734: The table is full

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import a old Vbulletin database but always getting this error

```
ERROR 1114 (HY000) at line 4734: The table 'session' is full
```

this database backup size is 2GB and my server have 8GB ram. I tried to add `innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend` and `innodb_file_per_table` to my.cnf but not solved my problem.

my complete my.cnf

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]

user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10

query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_file_per_table


[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am very familiar with `Vbulletin` database schema and tables.  I have converted dozens of VB sites to `Innodb storage engine`.

The reason that you are getting that error is because the `session` table is a `Memory` table. The `session` table(s) must have been quite full when you took this backup that you are trying to restore.  That, coupled with your overhead IO during the import, is filling up your RAM.  However, for VB to work properly, you do not actually need this table to be a `Memory` table.

In order to get around this you can convert your `session` table to `InnoDB`.

I would open the .sql file up in a text editor (if possible) and change where it says `ENGINE = MEMORY` for your `session` table to `InnoDB`, or use string replace:

```
sed -i 's/MEMORY/INNODB/g' yourfilename.sql
```

Comment: Thank you, I am trying now.

Comment: Hello Sir, I cant open my backup using notepad++ or any other text editor, do you know any way that I can edit using SSH?

Comment: on my Ubuntu server and also on my computer

Comment: Well for one if you use string replace you would not have to use notepad++...use `Putty` `http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html` to `SSH` to your ubuntu server and run string replace command there...If not you should be able to open the .sql file in 010 editor 'http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/'...I have opened really big files using this editor...

Comment: I used text editor for edit and I checked my session table ENGINE=HEAP I just replace with inodb and its worked.